# Meaning of 私だって、する時はするよ。

Tags: meaning

The feeling that I get is, “Even *I’ll* do [this] if the time comes,” but I’m not sure. I guess that the confusing bit is する時, which doesn’t mean much to me translated literally.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess that the confusing bit is する時, which doesn’t mean much to me translated literally.

In the full phrase 「する時はするよ」, the する時 is basically "when it's time [for me] to do something → when [I] do something".

I think a rendering of this into colloquial English might be *"I'll do it when I do it!"*  There's a sense of pushback against something said earlier.